# Excel Inserting Text in a Row Containing Specific Text

Tags: excel, insert, excel-formula

I am trying to come up with an excel formula for inserting a word into a blank cell if another cell contains specific text.

I have an inventory list and I need "0-1L PET" inserted at the end of each row that contains "pet."

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hlookup should work for this. Did you try that ?

Answer (score 0):

Where `pet` is the entire cell contents, something like:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("pet",A1:M1,0)),"","0-1L PET")
```

copied down should suit.